# How to prevent repeatative submit while using ajax or javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a controller in c# and inside the controller there is a save method. The save method saves/updates data that is submitted by submit button click and javascript. The problem is, if you click on the button multiple time, it should only process the very first click and rest of them should be identified as duplicate submit and should be discarded by controller. How to do this in c# mvc web application?

Comment: Give the form a one-use token. When the server receives the token back, it can decide if it has already been used or not. Or, you know, just disable the submit on the client side.

Comment: Is there any library for doing that or I need to manially maintain it?

Comment: There might be. I'm not sure. I usually just disable the button client-side (with appropriate feedback for the user).

Comment: You can disable the button while it is being saved or you can either have a boolean flag like "isSaving", so you can check this flag at the beginning of the action.

Comment: disabling button with javascript is not a good idea as if users know how to enable the flag then it has no benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button after it's clicked. So it can just be clicked once.

Comment: but anyone having javascript skill can enable it from user side

Comment: Yes of course it can be done. But if it works for now it's good I think. He can later think about encrypting and making his code more safe.

Comment: @eliaszaman Anyone with some skill could also perform the request manually

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way**

- when button clicked disabled it then actived again after you got response result from ajax! u can also add loader that make ur web look so cool!

```
<button id="btnSend" onClick="send()">submit</button>

<script>

btnSend=document.getElementById("btnSend");

function send(){

  btnSend.disabled=true;
  //set disabled button here

  $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
           url: "http://www.google.de",   
           async: false,
           success : function(text)
           {
                btnSend.disabled=false;
                //set active to button 
                
                // add your code here
           },

           fail : function(text)
           {
                btnSend.disabled=false;
                //set active to button 

                // add your code here
           }
  });

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also disable the button on the client side. But you could also check if the submitted data is different from the stored data. If no changes were made you could just return without further saving logic.

Should it be possible to just save the data once? Maybe a redirect to a different view after saving could be a possible solution in special cases.